# How to delete data from 2 tables in one mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to delete a country with specific id and cities that belong to that country .
I looked this up all over stack overflow and came up with this, but it still doesn't execute it..

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id =($_POST['id']);}

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lol");
    if ($connection-> connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed:". $connection-> connect_error);
    }
    $sql= "DELETE `countries`, `cities` FROM `countries` INNER JOIN `cities` on 
    `cities.fk_Country` = `countries.id` WHERE `countries.id` = $id";
    var_dump($sql);
    if(!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){
        echo 'Unable to delete the country. Try again!';
    } else {
        echo 'Succesfully deleted the country!';
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? (That's assuming you check for errors)

Comment: Use backticks on each individual table and column separately.

Comment: Show your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

delete your `cities` first since it has foreign key from `countries`.

```
$sql= "delete cities, countries
     from cities
     inner join countries on cities.fk_Country = countries.id
     where countries.id=$id";
```